# Keyboard shortcut to switch between keybindings in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, emacs, key-bindings, intellij-idea-2016

I'm a long time Emacs user who recently started developing with Intellij IDEA. 
I've installed the Emacs+ plugin to get some keyboard shortcuts. However the experience is not optimal as some bindings clash with the ones from Intellij.

Is there a possibility the switch between bindings on the fly ?

Say I'm editing a Java file with Emacs+ bindings and I would like to go to the declaration of the method on the current cursor position:

With the keyboard shortcut available, here is the setup:

1. I would first switch to Intellij default bindings (using the shortcut in question) and then press **Ctrl + B**
2. Go back to Emacs+ bindings to continue editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `View > Quick Switch Scheme ...` to switch key mapping bindings.

Here are some screenshots showing this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @glytching, Is there a way to have this on a keybiding ?

Comment: @SalmaneBah the switcher is activated via a keybinding, in the screenshot above it is `CTRL + BACKTICK`. So, to engage the "Emacs" keymap, I would enter: `CTRL + BACKTICK + 3 + 4`. Your keybinding might differ but if you have a look at the keybinding next to the `View > Quick Switch Scheme ...` menu item you'll see what your keybinding is.

Comment: Thanks @glytching, here is what I end up doing: remap `CTRL + BACKTICK`  to `CTRL + M` to use ease the switching.